# How do i capture the information displayed by a command execution in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I was executing an nslookup command on powershell and got the output as below:

Server:  *****.******.***

Address:  ***.***.***.**

*** *****.******.pvt can't find** .**.***.**: Server failed

The log capturing this output seems to be empty. is there any way i could capture the server failed error displayed on the host on to a variable?

Comment: Is that the output from `nslookup`? In that case the error is sent to stderr and you can redirect using `2>`. See `help about_Redirection`.

Comment: Thanks @Bill_Stewart, that helped me look at it in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to parse the results yourself, but this is how it works:

```
$variable = & nslookup args 2>&1

$variable
```

Comment: That helped, I could access the stderr by using $variable[0] and the normal output by $variable[2] and parse each of them as needed. Thanks!

Comment: Why parse output when you have the `[Net.Dns]` class?

Comment: [Net.Dns] class is actually much easier to use but when there is no host found, I have to, either way, parse through the stderr to get the exact information/type of the error in the catch statement.

Comment: It's not necessary to parse on failure in PowerShell. If you are in the `catch` block, you know what failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting the output from `nslookup`, there's no need when you can use the `[Net.Dns]` class in PowerShell. It returns a `[Net.IPHostEntry]` if the host exists. example:

```
try {
  if ( [Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("remoteserver") ) {
    "Host exists"
  }
}
catch [Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] {
  "Host does not exist"
}
```

The `GetHostEntry` method can resolve using a host name or an IP address.